# Image from database to Windows Forms

Tags: .net, sql-server, winforms

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SYS12;Initial Catalog=Teju;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Picture from tblImgData where id= " + listBox1.SelectedValue + " ", con);
    con.Open();
    byte[] byteImg = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(strfn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
    fs.Write(byteImg, 0, byteImg.Length-1);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(strfn);
}
```

This code showing error as "`Out of memory`." What might I be doing wrong, or how can I debug and solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use System.Drawing.Image Class to save file then directly assign this image to your picture box.

Check this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SYS12;Initial Catalog=Teju;Integrated Security=True");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Picture from tblImgData where id= " + listBox1.SelectedValue + " ", con);
    con.Open();
    byte[] byteImg = (byte[])cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    string strfn = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime());
   Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteImg);
Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);

img.Save(strfn , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not disposing of your objects won't help. Either use the [try/finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) blocks or a [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to clean up after yourself.